Gammastep unable to obtain GeoClue client path
I am on a Raspberry Pi 5 running Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. I wish to reduce the amount of blue light on my display. I downloaded gammastep, which gave me a message that seemed to imply I needed geoclue-2.0, so I downloaded geoclue-2.0 as well, but I get the following message when I run Gammastep Indicator:

What can I do so that gammastep will succeed in obtaining the GeoClue client path? (Incidentally, what is the GeoClue client path?)
I take it that gammastep is failing to "get location from provider" because it is "[u]nable to obtain GeoClue client path". So I presume that an answer to the question in bold will answer my other potential question, namely "What can I do so that gammastep will be able to 'get location from provider'?"
I am quite new to doing any but the most obvious of computer tasks so please assume as little knowledge as possible.
